# Can anyone help me our in understanding this particular example of union?

Tags: c

```
union {
    unsigned char raw[8];
    struct {
        uint8_t gz_method;
        uint8_t flag;
        uint32_t mtime;
        uint8_t xtra_flags_UNUSED;
        uint8_t os_flags_UNUSED;
    } PACKED formatted;
} header;
```

I am aware that the memory allocated by union is the maximum of its variables. but here is it that it allocates memory as that taken by the struct?

Comment: No, the size of the union is still same as its largest member. In this case the array and the (packed) structure is both the same size though (on a "normal" system where `char` is 8 bits).

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: If that struct really is packed on single-octets, the size of `formatted` and `raw` are the same. So whats the problem?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Is it the same size ?. Isn't `fomatted` 12 bytes after padding (if `sizeof(char) = 1 bytes` and `sizeof(int) = 4 bytes`)

Comment: @SaurabhMeshram *If* the structure is padded then yes it might be 12 bytes (or maybe even 10 bytes). But the `PACKED` symbol leads me to believe that the structure is packed (i.e. without padding), especially since the union is named `header` which leads me to guess it's part of a message-structure where padding is bad. Also, `sizeof(char)` is specified to always be `1`, no matter the actual bit-width of `char`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Agreed. Wasn't aware of that feature. However I found on `gcc` keyword `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` is used instead of `PACKED`. Edit: Must be a Macro!

Answer (score 3):

The whole union will take 8 bytes, because that's the size of its largest member.

Actually, in this case, both members have the same number of bytes (8). So, there are two ways to access to data: directly byte by byte or field by field.